# how to Inject core module objects in feature module

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger, multi-module

I am working on a multi-module android project. In main module we have a CoreComponent with CoreModule. CoreModule provides some objects. I want to inject those objects in our feature modules without creating new components.

What is the best way to do that?

Main Module

```java
@Component
CoreComponent ( modules = CoreModule.class )
   
@Module
CoreModule
```

Feature Module

```java
@Module
FeatureModule(includes = CoreModule.class)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike with [Dagger 1](https://square.github.io/dagger/1.x/dagger/dagger/Module.html#complete()), Dagger 2 modules don't have to be *complete*: CoreModule and FeatureModule can refer to bindings that they do not define. When Dagger 2 aggregates all of your modules to generate an implementation of your component, it will let you know whether you are missing any bindings.

```java
@Component(modules = {CoreModule.class, FeatureModule.class})
public interface CoreComponent {
}
   
@Module
public class CoreModule {
  @Provides public static A getA() { /* ... */ }
}

@Module /* no includes */
public class FeatureModule {
  /* Feature Module injects binding A from CoreModule, even without includes=  */
  @Provides public static B getB(A a) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Should you use `includes`? It depends. If you have FeatureModule include CoreModule, then any time you refer to FeatureModule it will automatically include CoreModule, which can make FeatureModule easier to use, and Dagger will remove any duplicate inclusions of FeatureModule. However, if you want to use the bindings in FeatureModule but a MockCoreModule in your integration tests, then you won't be able to let FeatureModule include CoreModule because it will presumably conflict in bindings with MockCoreModule.

Notably, this assumes that FeatureModule and CoreModule are a part of the same overall Component, because you've only shown us one component. If you have a separate FeatureComponent, then you'll need to list it in your question; the relationship (if any) between CoreComponent and FeatureComponent: component dependency, subcomponent, or unrelated separate component. Each of those cases will be different.